# Get results of observable after pressing ENTER and delayed results

Tags: rxjs, observable

With observable, I have a `searchTextStream`, an `enterKeyStream`, and `resultStream`.

I have something like this for searching and getting results (which I am sure I could improve to use a cold observable)

```
this.searchTermStream.asObservable()
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe(term => {
        this.search(term, (result) => {
            this.resultStream.next(result);
        });
    });
```

I am trying to get the result of the data on ENTER, but with the latest of resultStream. The caveat is that I don't want to get the old resultStream if I was typing.

The three scenarios

1. The results are in. I press ENTER I want to get the results. A `combineLatest` is quite simple here.
2. The results are in, however I type more, then press ENTER. I don't want the stale results, but wait for the new results to come first in, then execute my ENTER stream.
3. No results are in, I press ENTER nothing should happen. A `combineLatest` would NOT be good in this scenario.

How should this be wired? I am probably missing some knowledge about operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withLatestFrom` and `switchMap` should satisfy your requirements. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html
[code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-u9vkyp)

```
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { withLatestFrom, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map, merge, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

const searchText$ = new Subject<string>();
const enterKey$ = new Subject<void>();
const result$ = new Subject<any>();

function search(text: string): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this.search(text, result => {
      observer.next(result)
    })
  })
}

const debouncedInput$ = searchText$.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map(text => ({text, enter: false}))  
)

enterKey$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(searchText$),
  map(([_, text]) => ({text, enter: true}))
).pipe(
  merge(debouncedInput$),
  switchMap(({text}) => search(text))
).subscribe((result) => {
  result$.next(result)
})
```